# How to change the height of a Kendo UI numerictextbox?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, frontend

I've tried somthing like

```
    .k-numeric-wrap .k-state-default{
         height: 24px;
         line-height: 24px;  
    }
```

and it makes the numerictextbox`s bottom border disappered.
I've also tried

```
.k-formatted-value .k-input{
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

.k-select{
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;  
}

.k-numeric-wrap .k-state-default .k-state-hover{
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px; 
}

.k-widget .k-numerictextbox{
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px; 
}

.k-numeric-wrap .k-state-default{
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px; 
}
```

but none of them works.

Comment: have you tried -  .k-numeric-wrap .k-state-default{
         height: 24px !important;
         line-height: 24px !important;  
    }

Comment: @Chrislaar123 using `!important` with the `height` tag did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 .k-numeric-wrap.k-expand-padding .k-input {
   height: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this following code in Chrome, it fixed the bottom border missing at 100% zoom issue.

```
.k-numerictextbox .k-input {
    height: 30px !important;//Could be set at any height 
}
```